# The face color support in glTF

Tags: gltf

I have a glTF face material question: In the source model, it contains a mesh body with two different face materials. How export the different face materials in one source mesh body into one glTF mesh?

Example:
The source model is a cube with red and blue face colors with the texture material.
The glTF file: a cube with two primitives under one glTF mesh. For one primitive, set its material color as red; for another primitive, set its material color as blue. Is it a correct and a good solution? Is there any other better way?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use a (very small) texturemap to indicate the different face colors.

Each glTF material corresponds to the shader program, texture stack, and material settings used in one draw call.  If you ask for different settings, for example different `baseColorFactor` values on some of the polygons, then a typical rendering engine will need to make more than one draw call to get the whole mesh rendered.

In your cube example, this means a typical rendering engine would likely set some `uniform` value to red, then load just the vertices of the red faces of the cube into the graphics pipeline, and then run the whole pipeline.  Wait for the vertex shader to do its thing, the rasterizer cuts up triangles into fragments, the fragment shader colors all the fragments red, and pixels come out the other side.  Then, once that whole pipeline is flushed clean of data and reset, only then will the `uniform` value be modified from red to blue.  Now, load the vertices for the blue faces, and restart the whole pipeline from the beginning.  Ouch.  Too slow.

Instead, put a small texturemap with a red area and a blue area.  The cube faces don't share normals and some don't share UVs, so there will be 24 verts on the cube.  The rendering engine loads the shader program, loads the texturemap, and then dumps all 24 verts into the graphics pipeline, and lets it rip.  The whole mesh can be done in a single material in this manner, using a single glTF `primitive` resulting in a single draw call.

This much effort to optimize away a single draw call isn't worth it in a vacuum, but if this is indicative of a pattern that is repeated often in the model, or the mesh or model is instanced a lot of times, the optimization becomes worthwhile.  If each animation frame climbs into the thousands of draw calls, some users on some systems may start to notice the lag.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaining. I added my glTF file mesh and material segments in my post. It seems that a primitive only can reference one glTF material. If use one primitive to represent all six faces, how can we achieve six faces to display different materials in one primitive? Sorry for still being unclear on 'texturemap' concept.

Comment: Yes, one material per primitive, by design.  One other option I forgot about, instead of using a texturemap, you can assign colors with the `COLOR_0` vertex attribute.  The material should be white, and then you would put red and blue colors as vertex attributes.

Comment: I try to understand your texturemap way. In the following link, it answers the question "How do I apply a different image to each face of a cube?" It seems that the third answer is similar to your texturemap way, correct?https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html

Comment: For using COLOR_0, this way is ok to have a primitive if there is no any texture image for the faces. If the blue faces also attach a texture image 1, and the red faces attach another texture image 2, using COLOR_0 vertex color still can achieve only a primitive for the cube?